# Filter AutoCompleteTextView result with 2 criteria

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a RTL application which displays the customer name in the AutoCompleteTextView widget.now my toString() is like this,so it filters the result based on the name. now i want to go a step further to allow my users to search for a customer based on the name and code. How can i do it. i am using Android version 2.3.3.

```
public String toString() {
    return getName;
}
```

=========

```
    private void loadCustomers() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                customers = getConnection().getCustomers();
                BaseKaizenActivity.getStorageManager().setCustomers(
                        customers);
                Log.d("---", "loaded customers: " + customers.size());

                handleSuccess(customers);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.d("--- ERROR ---", exc.getMessage());
                handleException(exc.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

=========

```
private void handleSuccess(final List<Customer> customers) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final ArrayAdapter<Customer> customerSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(
                    MainMenuActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, customers);
            customerSpinner
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            customerTextView.setAdapter(customerSpinner);


            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

==========

```
@Override
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "customer"));
    try {
        String response = executeHttpPost(params);
        String[] result = split(response);

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        for (int i = 2; i < result.length; i += 18) {
            String id = result[i + 0];
            String code = result[i + 1];

            String name = result[i + 3];

            String address = result[i + 4];
            String type = result[i + 5];

            String phoneNo = result[i + 6];
            String mobileNo = result[i + 7];
            String faxNo = result[i + 8];       

            Customer customer = new Customer(id, code, name, address, type,phoneNo,mobileNo,faxNo);
                    customers.add(customer);

        }
        Log.d("----", "" + customers.size());           
        return customers;
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e("----", exc.getMessage(), exc);
        throw new ConnectionException(exc.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code in which you are using the above method to retrieve the name.

Comment: bro, post the code in which your are executing toString method to retrieve the name by returning getName().You might be using it in your adapter.

Comment: i suppose AutoCompleteTextView does that itself.i am not executing that toString() anywhere as far as i know.please bear with me if i am missing something

Comment: i added another code,hope that is what you meant

Comment: Yes,I had gone through the code,btw sorry for misunderstanding.you need to work with custom adapter which can do filtering for you unlike ArrayAdapter.

Comment: thanks for your feedback,can you please help me with it